# Dynamically added controls in gridview (checkbox) disappear after postback in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, postback

I added a dynamic create checkbox to grid view column but it gives me null value on button click.

The checkbox disappear after post back.

Here is my code

```
protected void grdreport_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    int temp = e.Row.Cells.Count;

    temp--;

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

        if (temp >= 3)
        {
            strheadertext1 = grdreport.HeaderRow.Cells[3].Text;

            CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox();

            cb1.Text = e.Row.Cells[3].Text;

            e.Row.Cells[3].Controls.Add(cb1);

        }

    }
}
```

and on my button click where i check value of checkbox is checked or not  is

```
foreach (GridViewRow item in grdreport.Rows)
{
    if (item.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        CheckBox checkbox1 = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("cb1");
        // cb1.Checked = true;
        if (checkbox1.Checked)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using dynamic controls you need to rebind the GridView data on every PostBack. So usually you would use an IsPostBack check and bind data in there. But do not do that now.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //normally you would bind here
    if (IsPostBack == false)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = source;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    //but when using dynamic control inside a gridview, bind here
    GridView1.DataSource = source;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Update

And you have to give a dynamic control an ID. You are looking for `cb1`, but you never assign that ID to the checkbox.

```
CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox();
cb1.ID = "cb1";
```

Comment: still checkbox has null value @vdwwd

Comment: thanks @VDWWD  its Work Fine but new issue occur on button click i get value for row items it always give first row value whenever i check checkbox of second row 
        foreach (GridViewRow row in grdreport.Rows)
        {


            CheckBox checkbox1 = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("cb1");
            checkbox1.Checked = true;
            if (checkbox1.Checked)
            {
                string itemname = row.Cells[0].Text;
                 string particular = row.Cells[1].Text;
                string qty = row.Cells[2].Text;
            }

        }

    }'

Comment: You are looping all the rows, so you have to make sure you get the correct row.

Comment: how to get that check row @VDWWD

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the value of a dynamically created control during PostBack, you need to recreate the control with the same ID in the `OnInit` method. There are very few cases when this is necessary or justifies the effort that you have to put in to make this work - especially in scenarios that involve lists or grids.

That being said, there are some alternatives that you can use to show the checkbox only for some items. One idea would be to add a normal checkbox column (or for more complex scenarios a template column). Either use code or CSS to hide the checkbox in the rows that you do not want to see the checkbox. So the object would be there, but the users would not see it in the rows where it is hidden. This usually is much easier than the dynamic approach.